# Is it possible to link to a class method directly in cakephp 3?

Tags: hyperlink, cell, cakephp-3.0

We can generate a block of code using cells without appController interposition. Is it possible to have an html link to cell methods or other methods without appController interposition? Something like this:

```
$this->Html->link('Show help' , ['controller'=>'Cell::help' , 'action'=>'show']);
```

Comment: Why would you even want to do that, they are called "_View_ Cells" for a reason?

Comment: my appController generates some default codes that I don't need in an ajax requests but I need them in other requests. I think if I can place my ajax functions in somewhere out of appController cycle, then my problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not what *view* cells are ment for, they are elements on steroids, and as their name suggests, ment to be used in views.

If you want your app controller to do specific things only for non-AJAX requests, then you could for example do them conditionally

```
if (!$this->request->is('ajax')) {
    // ...
}
```

See also **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Checking Request Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#checking-request-conditions)**